# How can i install visual studio express edition for web in windows vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, visual-studio, operating-systems

I am using a windows vista operating system. I want to install visual studio express edition for web. But from system requirements i understood that vista doesn't support express edition?
what can i do? whether windows 7 support express edition? If so, which version? How can upgrade windows vista to windows 7? What are the requirements needed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to grab some edition of the VS2008 or VS2005- they should be compatible with Vista. 
Here are the steps to upgrade the OS (VS worked on my laptop with W7 so I think this is better approach):
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-vista-to-windows-7#T1=tab01

Comment: I need more help

Comment: what do you mean? I can grab a couple of serverfault users and go to your place and configure everything instead of you. Or not really?